# how to find spherical coordinates of adjacent vertices surrounding central vertex in A3/D3 lattice

Tags: geometry, tessellations

How could you define (using spherical coordinate system) all the adjacent vertices directly connected to a central vertex in a tetrahedral octahedral honeycomb? Alternatively it would be useful to get the answer in cartesian coordinates and I could convert it myself. If this is too much effort, please refer me to a site that has this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, what you are asking about is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron  around the origin which serves as the "vertex figure."

I had the locations exactly where you want them, sum of integer coordinates even. Now, the vertex figure has six square faces, these are sliced halfway through each octahedron with a vertex at the origin; what are these squares? More typing in a minute...

One of these six squares is
$$  (1,0,1); \; (1,1,0); \; (1,0,-1); \; (1,-1,0). $$
$$  (-1,0,1); \; (-1,1,0); \; (-1,0,-1); \; (-1,-1,0). $$

$$  (0,1,1); \; (1,1,0); \; (0,1,-1); \; (-1,1,0). $$
$$  (0,-1,1); \; (1,-1,0); \; (0,-1,-1); \; (-1,-1,0). $$

$$  (0,1,1); \; (1,0,1); \; (0,-1,1); \; (-1,0,1). $$
$$  (0,1,-1); \; (1,0,-1); \; (0,-1,-1); \; (-1,0,-1). $$

The same collection of twelve points (each point in two of the squares) make up eight triangles.
$$  (0,1,1); \; (1,0,1); \; (1,1,0).  $$
And seven more.

I see how to describe the eight triangles in an orderly manner; for each of the following eight matrices, let the three rows be the corners of a triangle.

One
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right),
$$

Two
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right),
$$

Three
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0
\end{array}
\right),
$$

Four
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right),
$$

Five
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 0
\end{array}
\right),
$$

Six
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right),
$$

Seven
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & 0
\end{array}
\right),
$$

Eight
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & 0
\end{array}
\right),
$$

Comment: wow, amazing... it really helps when you chop the octahedra in half and focus on the square bases of the newly formed pyramids...

Comment: seems like everything is on a tilt... so I totally get why they taught us cartesian coordinates with tessellating cubes, rather than the tetrahedral-octahedral honeycomb... I was playing around with cutting up cubes, and I was wondering why they never taught us tetrahedral-octahedral honeycomb for making graphs, like a coordinate system (i'm obsessed with not using orthogonal axis)... also I get that these cuboctahedra are not tessellating, but there are many cuboctahedra intruding on each other in tetrahedral-octahedral honeycomb, as there is a cuboctahedron centered around each vertex...

Comment: thanks, this was amazingly informative...

Comment: @JasandPruski, I put in the eight triangles.

Comment: I don't understand matrices yet, but I rented a precalc book from the library to learn matrices, so I'm gonna study this some more... this will boost my motivation when I'm learning matrices, kind of make it artsy for me... again, thanks...

Comment: @JasandPruski, for your purpose, they are just three rows each, each row giving the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of the three points making one of the equilateral triangles.

Comment: oh, that helps...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to place the centers for a tiling by Voronoi cells, all rhombic dodecahedra, is all integer points $(x,y,z)$ such that $x+y+z$ is even. I think that is what you want, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral-octahedral_honeycomb#A3.2FD3_lattice

The center is the origin, and there are twelve immediate neighbors, one coordinate remains $0$ and the others are $1$ or $-1.$

Also see the "Basis" at http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/D3.html

Comment: what i don't get is where the rhombic dodecahedra come from when you view the tetrahedral octahedral honeycomb from it's "vertex arrangement". I apologize if this is an obvious question.

Comment: @JasandPruski, you had best read the wikipedia article really, really carefully. I do not know what you mean by "vertex arrangement." You asked about a lattice and I told you how to place it in $\mathbb R^3.$ If you wanted to know where to put a collection of tetrahedra and octahedra that together tile space, i can also do that; but the best way puts the center of one of the octahedra at the origin, which is why I figured you wanted this lattice. Do you know what a Voronoi cell of a lattice is ?

Comment: yep you got me, I am very math challenged. calc II is as far as I got. I am a biologist with an artistic interest in math/geometry. so were the "edges connecting to the vertex in honeycomb converted to faces of rhombic dodecahedra" and the "solids meeting at a vertex in honeycomb converted to vertices in rhombic dodecahedra" in the rhombic dodecahedra, since rhombic dodecahedra has 14 vertices and 12 faces, while the vertex in the tetra-octa honeycomb had 14 solids meeting at the vertex, with 12 edges emerging from this vertex point. Again I apologize if I am using the wrong terminology.

Comment: "If you wanted to know where to put a collection of tetrahedra and octahedra that together tile space, i can also do that; but the best way puts the center of one of the octahedra at the origin" why is it the best way to put an octahedra in the center, why not use a vertex as a center?